# Detect if browser is performing a redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, browser, refresh

On my project I have a warning message that apears on every case of error.
It is not anything fancy, just some jquery transitions when a event is fired.
I have some pages that on load fetch some data with get requests.
When I do a redirect or a reload the connection with the server fails and triggers the warning to appear.
I believe that this behavior will confuse the users.

Is there a way to detect when a browser is performing a redirect or a reload in order to disable the warning?

**Edit 1**
I get an error because the browser is dropping the connection with server due to the redirect/reload.
So it is logical to get an error in my console.
The illogical thing is to throwgh a warning for something that the browser had to do in order to complete my request.
I don't need an event, I need a way to check the browsers condition.

**Edit 2**
I should have said this earlier, but the warning is shown before the redirect or reload is complete.

Comment: I'd personally be more concerned about the server error, but in answer to your question there is no "afterredirect" event, or similar.  You could set a cookie *before* redirect, and don't show the error if that cookie value exists (clearing it every time you check, of course).

Comment: @Archer could you check my update?

Comment: How is a reload any different to the first visit to the page?  I don't get why there should be a server error at all and I think you'd be spending your time better fixing that issue, than hiding it with something else.  My cookies suggestion will still do the "something else", after your question update.

Comment: @Archer When you leave a page with active connections the browser cuts the connection. This is correct since you are leaving the page and the connection is no longer needed. In reality there is no error, javascript handles it as an error. I can't stop the browser from closing a connection when I give him the instruction to drop everything that he is doing to perform a redirection.

Comment: Closing a connection should not force an error when the next page loads, which is what your question sounds like you're saying.  Are you now saying that you get the error before redirection or reload?

Comment: @Archer Ok I see that I confused you. Yes I mean before the redirect or reload. I will add to my post. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since I couldn't find a way to detect the browsers state I decided to go with jquery beforeunload event which I tried to avoid.
Using this event the solution is simple.

**Step 1** Create a control var set to true;

```
example = true;
```

**Step 2** Bind the before unload event to invert the var.

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
    example  = false;
});
```

**Step 3** Check your var before you execute your code.

```
if(example){
  controlled code...
}
```

The code will execute will the browser stands still but will be disabled if a redirect or reload is executed.